# How do I force tikz to use CMYK everywhere (also in shadings)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, shading

I'm doing a poster with the `baposter` which uses `tikz` and at some point realized that some colors that should be identical are not. It turns out that `tikz` apparently resorts to RGB color space as soon as there is a shading involved, whereas I'm doing the  poster (a I intend to print it...) in CMYK (which is also the default in the `baposter` class).

Now my question is: How do I force `tikz` to use CMYK everywhere?

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

%%% uncomment to use CMYK
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{1,0,0.57,0.42} 

%%% uncomment to use RGB
% \usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
% \definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{009440}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pdfcompresslevel=0

\begin{document}

\color{mygreen}{MY TEXT}

\tikz 
  \shade [left color=mygreen,right color=mygreen] 
  (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
%
\tikz 
  \fill [mygreen] 
  (1,1) rectangle (2,2);

\end{document}
```

The two boxes, which should have the same color, have not. The shaded box should have the same color as the solid box and the text.

(Note: this question is not so much about the `baposter` class, however, as `baposter` uses `tikz` the underlying problem leads to the fact that the frames of the boxes and the shadings in the header of the boxes have different colors.)

Comment: I might be wrong but TikZ doesn't know how to interpolate in different color models and relies on `xcolor`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, the requested feature is unsupported.

In general, your approach works fine: if you write

```
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
```

all color definitions result in cmyk colors. But shadings are special: they are not based on xcolor's drivers but on pgf's drivers. And the pgf drivers for shadings supports RGB, nothing else. I believe that pgf calls colorspace conversion routines in order to convert from cmyk back to RGB whenever it generates shadings.

What you need is a feature request for PGF in order to respect the global `xcolor` configuration and to generate shadings in that color space.

---

There may be work-arounds. These, however, depend on the urgency - if you say that you will file feature requests and will live with the restriction, that is fine.

If you really need a workaround, you can continue reading.

The work-around that I have in mind is to use pgfplots. It has a couple of plot-related shadings and comes with its own related drivers. These, in turn, support cmyk - and most shadings can be expressed as plot-based shadings. The effort to convert these shadings from tikz pictures which have a super embedding into your pictures to pgfplots plots would be medium.

Here is an attempt in this direction:

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{minimal}

%%% uncomment to use CMYK
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{1,0,0.57,0.42} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

%%% uncomment to use RGB
% \usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
% \definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{009440}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\color{mygreen}{MY TEXT}

\tikz 
  \shade [left color=mygreen,right color=mygreen] 
  (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
%
\tikz 
  \fill [mygreen] 
  (1,1) rectangle (2,2);

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % this statement is needed for pgfplots v1.8. 
    % pgfplots 1.9 or newer inherits it from
    % \usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}:
    \pgfplotsset{mesh/colorspace explicit color output=cmyk}

    \begin{axis}[
        x=1cm,y=1cm,
        hide axis,
        view={0}{90}]
    \addplot[surf,mesh/color input=explicit,shader=interp] 
    table[meta=cdata] {
        x y cdata
        1 1 color=mygreen
        2 1 color=yellow

        1 2 color=mygreen
        2 2 color=yellow
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It relies on a surface plot with explicit color using the rectangular coordinates (1cm,1cm) (2cm,2cm) and the colors are listed in the table. The verbose syntax `color=<name>` is necessary to distinguish from something like `0,0,1` or `gray=0.5`.

Comment: My follow-up question would be how to use `pgfplots` to do the background shading in the `baposter` class.

Comment: hm. Would it help if something like `\shade [left color=mygreen,right color=mygreen] ` would be expressed by means of a `pgfplots` shading? Otherwise you would need to compose a(nother) minimal working example illustrating the problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer with an initial attempt. This illustrates what would need to be done and can (hopefully) be generalized to what you need in your poster.

Comment: Still, a feature request for tikz/pgf would be a good idea.

Comment: I'm surprised this works: As `pgfplots` is based on `tikz` why can it do shadings "better" than `tikz` itself? And as it apparently can do: Can't I just use how `pgfplots` does the shading directly? (And yes, that would be helpful as I'd need to translate the `shadedraw` command.)

Comment: Actually, I just saw there's already a feature request concerning just this (from 2007...): http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/29/

Comment: Surface/mesh/patch plots require different types of shadings compared to axial or radial shadings which are common for tikz. In fact, the use-cases appear to be largely orthogonal to each other. If you have specific questions how to generate pgfplots shadings "directly", you should ask new question(s).

Comment: New question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137228/.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I posted a [follow up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210575/4918) and I would be really glad if you can take a look at it :-)

Answer (score 8):

## Update

`tikz` now supports this feature since version 3.1.3. Just make sure you have `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}` before you load `tikz`.

---

It's quite late for the OP, but if someone faces this problem, there is now a package ([pgf-cmykshadings](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-cmykshadings)) that does just that. According to its documentation "The pack­age at­tempts to pro­duce shad­ings con­sis­tent with the cur­rently se­lected xcolor colour model. The `rgb`, `cmyk`, and `gray` colour mod­els from the `xcolor` pack­age are sup­ported."

## MWE

Here's a MWE demonstrating how to use `pgf-cmykshadings` to produce a CMYK shading as asked in the question. You need to load `pgf-cmykshadings` *before* `tikz` for the shadings to be set up correctly. It's a good idea to load `xcolor` with the `cmyk` option *before* `pgf-cmykshadings` to ensure that all colours will be output in CMYK and there will be no colour mismatches.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{cmyk}{1,0,0.57,0.42} 
\usepackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\color{mygreen}{MY TEXT}
\bigskip

\tikz 
  \shade [left color=mygreen,right color=mygreen] 
  (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
%
\tikz 
  \fill [mygreen] 
  (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\bigskip

\tikz
  \shade [left color=cyan, right color=magenta]
  (1,1) rectangle (5,2);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `pgf-cmykshadings` is indeed designed to answer this question (I'm the author). The original question can be solved by modifying the MWE to load `pgf-cmykshadings` *after* `xcolor`, but *before* `tikz`. You will then get CMYK colours everywhere, including in shadings. All `LaTeX` engines and drivers are supported in v1.1 (v1.0 didn't support dvips).

Comment: Actually, please use at least v1.1a (I missed a missing percent sign!) in the first two versions uploaded to CTAN. :(