# Drawing a box with shading in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, color, shading

As a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136818), or more precisely [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137031), I'd like to know how to do the equivalent of

```
\shadedraw
  [shading=axis,left color=green,right color=orange,color=blue,line width=2] 
  (2,0) -- (2,1) 
  {[rounded corners=1em] -- (3,1)} --
  (3,0) -- (2,0);
```

using pgfplots such that the shading is done in the CMYK colorspace.

(This would then be used in `baposter` as a replacement for the shading in the headers of the boxes.)

Comment: May I ask why you insist on CMYK model for a poster? You can ask for the CMYK version from the printer if you feel there will be a significant difference. In Photoshop (if you have it) there was a *Gamut Warning* thingy when I was keen on using Adobe stuff. That can tell you if there will be a significant problem by turning the areas in the gray.

Comment: The reason is that I have a shading from white to light gray in the background. I cannot predict what this would look like in print if it's converted from RGB to CMYK, so I'd prefer to use CMYK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already stressed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137031, this answer should be considered a workaround: the correct solution would be to "wait for the feature request in tikz".

Naturally, that can take longer than having a clumsy work-around at hand.

Here is an attempt to use a `pgfplots` surface plot to simulate your desired filled shading:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
% if you have v1.8, write:
%\pgfplotsset{mesh/colorspace explicit color output=cmyk}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
    \shadedraw
  [shading=axis,left color=green,right color=orange,color=blue,line width=2] 
  (2,0) -- (2,1) 
  {[rounded corners=1em] -- (3,1)} --
  (3,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
    \draw
  [color=blue,line width=4pt] 
  (2,0) -- (2,1) 
  {[rounded corners=1em] -- (3,1)} --
  (3,0) -- cycle;
    \clip
  (2,0) -- (2,1) 
  {[rounded corners=1em] -- (3,1)} --
  (3,0) -- cycle;

    \begin{axis}[
        % necessary to match up coordinate systems:
        xmin=0,ymin=0,
        anchor=origin,
        x=1cm,y=1cm,
        hide axis,
    ]
    \addplot[surf,mesh/color input=explicit,shader=interp] 
    table[meta=cdata] {
        x y cdata
        2 0 color=green
        2 1 color=green

        3 0 color=orange
        3 1 color=orange
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both are tikzpictures, the first one is replicated from your question and the second one is based on `pgfplots`. You see that it is considerably more involved: it installs a `clip` path to restrict the shading to your "rounded" rectangle, then it draws the outline of the clip path (for some reason, pgf rejects it if I say `\draw[clip]` with the remaining options). The rest is a `pgfplots` axis which is forced to use the same coordinate system as the outer `tikz` picture (requiring a bunch of keys explained in section "TikZ interoperability" in the pgfplots manual).

This answer will hopefully become superfluos once TikZ supports CMYK shadings.

Comment: As the feature request is almost 6 years old, I have little hope this will ever be implemented. Thus thanks a lot for your workaround.

Comment: Actually, I considered implementing the TikZ driver... it is not particularly difficult. But I'm glad the workaround helps. The message was more for others than for you.