# How to make a longitudinal sine wave shading with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, shading

At the moment I use TikZ shadings to show up longitudinal waves in my document like this:

[image: sine wave]

The shading is white where the sine is –1 and blue where the sine equals 1. This looks ok, but unfortunately it is in RGB and I need a clean **CMYK** document. The above mentioned questions led me to use `pgfplots` to make the shading but actually I don’t know how …

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{wave}{cmyk}{1,0.35,0,0}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \tikzset{
        samples=100,
    }
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

% Variables
\pgfmathsetmacro\T{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\A{0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\D{\N*\T}

\begin{document}
\section{With TikZ}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Shading
    \coordinate (C) at (0.25pt,0);% small overlapping
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\N} {
        \shade [shading=axis, right color=white, left color=wave, shading angle=90]
            ($(\x*\T-\T,-\A)-(C)$) rectangle ++($(\T/2,2*\A)+(C)$);
        \shade [shading=axis, left color=white, right color=wave, shading angle=90]
            ($(\x*\T-\T/2,-\A)-(C)$) rectangle ++($(\T/2,2*\A)+(C)$);
    }
    % Cosine Wave
    \draw [black] plot [id=sine, domain=0:\D]
        function {\A*cos(2*pi/\T*x)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{With PGFplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot [domain=0:\D] {\A*cos(2*pi/\T*x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It would be great if I can only specify the function, e.g. `\A*cos(2*pi/\T*x)` and a rectangle to clip the shading, and the rest of the work is done by TeX …

---

**Bonus question:** How can I imitate a radial shading like this one

[image: radial shading]

which is done with

```
\pgfdeclareradialshading{wave}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}%
    {%
        color(0.0cm)=(white);
        color(0.01cm)=(white);
        color(0.1cm)=(wave);
        color(0.2cm)=(white);
        color(0.3cm)=(wave);
        color(0.4cm)=(white);
        color(0.5cm)=(wave);
        color(0.6cm)=(white);
        color(0.7cm)=(wave);
        color(0.8cm)=(white);
        color(0.9cm)=(wave)
    }
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade [shading=wave] circle [radius=5] ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, that this is a follow up question of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136818/4918 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137228/4918.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an attempt to replicate the same dimensions with `pgfplots`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{wave}{cmyk}{1,0.35,0,0}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \tikzset{
        samples=100,
    }
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

% Variables
\pgfmathsetmacro\T{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\A{0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\D{\N*\T}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Shading
    \coordinate (C) at (0.25pt,0);% small overlapping
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\N} {
        \shade [shading=axis, right color=white, left color=wave, shading angle=90]
            ($(\x*\T-\T,-\A)-(C)$) rectangle ++($(\T/2,2*\A)+(C)$);
        \shade [shading=axis, left color=white, right color=wave, shading angle=90]
            ($(\x*\T-\T/2,-\A)-(C)$) rectangle ++($(\T/2,2*\A)+(C)$);
    }
    % Cosine Wave
    \draw [black] plot [id=sine, domain=0:\D]
        function {\A*cos(2*pi/\T*x)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        hide axis,
        colormap={custom}{color=(white) color=(wave)},
        trig format plots=rad,
        x=1cm,
        y=1cm,
        z=0cm,
    ]
    \addplot3[
        domain=0:\D,samples=100,
        domain y=-\A:\A,samples y=2,
        surf,shader=interp,
    ] {\A*cos(2*pi/\T * x)};

    \addplot [domain=0:\D,samples=100] {\A*cos(2*pi/\T*x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to use a `surf` plot which is viewed from top. The color data is the value of `f(x,y)`, i.e. the cos value, mapped linearly into the colormap. The smallest color is "white" and the largest is "wave". The shading is generated in CMYK as is the color interpolation.

---

A radial shading can be done using `data cs=polar` (which means x= angle, y =radius):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\definecolor{wave}{cmyk}{1,0.35,0,0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

% Variables
\pgfmathsetmacro\T{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro\A{0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\D{\N*\T}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        hide axis,
        colormap={custom}{color=(white) color=(wave)},
        trig format plots=rad,
        x=1cm,
        y=1cm,
        z=0cm,
    ]
    \clip (-\D/2,-\D/2) rectangle (\D/2, \D/2);
    \addplot3[
        data cs=polar,
        domain=0:2*pi,
        domain y=0:\D,samples y=25,
        surf,shader=interp,
    ] {\A*sin(2*pi/\T * y)};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is actually, what I tried but I had `every plot/.style={smooth}` in my document which interfered with the surface plots and made them becoming dimly lines instead …

Comment: Could you please explain – if possible – how to make a radial shading with this approach (see my edited question)?

Comment: I have added a solution with radial shadings by means of a surface plot

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Perfect...

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the gnuplot version of pgfplots if you want it to be more flexible.

Here is an exemple of the interference pattern of 7 point sources with the following parameters * \Lambda is the wavelength * \DistanceSources is the constant distance between the sources * the amplitude can be chosen with the function "amorti" but will be constant within a radius of \Cutoff from the source * \RetardIIvsI is the constant phase shift between two adjacent sources * \Date is the constant phase added to all sources.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{-6}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{-6}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{6}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{6}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Lambda}{.5}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\DistanceSources}{\Lambda/2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\CentreI}{-4*\DistanceSources}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\CentreII}{\CentreI+\DistanceSources}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\CentreIII}{\CentreII+\DistanceSources}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\CentreIV}{\CentreIII+\DistanceSources}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\CentreV}{\CentreIV+\DistanceSources}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\CentreVI}{\CentreV+\DistanceSources}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\CentreVII}{\CentreVI+\DistanceSources}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Cutoff}{\Lambda/10}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\RetardIIvsI}{pi/2}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Date}{0}

   \begin{axis}[colormap/blackwhite,
      view ={0}{90},
      xlabel = $x$,
      ylabel = $y$,
      extra x ticks = ,
      extra x tick labels = ,
      extra y ticks = ,
      extra y tick labels = ,
      xmin = \xmin,
      ymin = \ymin,
      xmax = \xmax,
      ymax = \ymax,
      domain = \xmin:\xmax,
      samples = 50
      ]
      \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
          set isosamples 50,50;
          amorti (centre,xy,y,cutoff)= 1;
          interf(centre,date,x,y,cutoff,lambda,retard) =%
          amorti(centre,x,y,cutoff)%
          * cos(date-2*pi*sqrt((x-centre)**2 + y**2)/lambda-retard);
          splot [x=\xmin:\xmax] [y=\ymin:\ymax] 1./7.*(%
             interf(\CentreI,\Date,x,y,\Cutoff,\Lambda,0)%
           + interf(\CentreII,\Date,x,y,\Cutoff,\Lambda,\RetardIIvsI)%
           + interf(\CentreIII,\Date,x,y,\Cutoff,\Lambda,2*\RetardIIvsI)%
           + interf(\CentreIV,\Date,x,y,\Cutoff,\Lambda,3*\RetardIIvsI)%
           + interf(\CentreV,\Date,x,y,\Cutoff,\Lambda,4*\RetardIIvsI)%
           + interf(\CentreVI,\Date,x,y,\Cutoff,\Lambda,5*\RetardIIvsI)%
           + interf(\CentreVII,\Date,x,y,\Cutoff,\Lambda,6*\RetardIIvsI)%
           ) 
          };
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]