# CMYK Shading with relative coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shading

I am trying to in a way automate the shading issue described here: [Drawing a box with shading in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137228/drawing-a-box-with-shading-in-pgfplots)

The general goal is to put a working code part in my style definition using `append after command`.

But actually I am trying to find out how to solve some general problems.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=2ex,gray!20,thin] (-10ex,-7ex) grid (10ex, 7ex);

\node[draw, rectangle, rounded corners=6pt] at (0ex, 0ex) (md) {My Design};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\clip
(md.north west)  [rounded corners=6pt] -- (md.north east) 
-- (md.south east) --
(md.south west) -- cycle;

\newdimen\nwx
\pgfextractx{\nwx}{(cd.north west)}

\begin{axis}[
% necessary to match up coordinate systems:
xmin=-10ex,ymin=-7ex,
anchor=origin,
x=1ex,y=1ex,
hide axis,
]
\addplot[surf,mesh/color input=explicit,shader=interp] 
table[meta=cdata] {
    x y cdata
    -6.5 2 color=gray!40
    -6.5 -2 color=gray!40

    5.5 2 color=white
    5.5 -2 color=white
};
\end{axis}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Current Example]

As in the code above the clipping-part was somewhat easy to solve.

Now I have to change the plot accordingly. For this I need the x and y values of the used coordinates in the clip-part to insert them automatically and not manual.

Trying to use the `let` command in `\addplot` didn't work. So I tried to extract the values with `\pgfextractx`. But this brought me to another problem: 
The result is given with the unit `pt` and produces an error. Additionally it would be nicer if I could use ex-values in the axis and don't have to change this to pt, because I think this could be an issue when I scale the graphics.

So is there a solution to convert the value to an `ex` unit and then remove the unit from the string?

Better solutions in general are also welcome! 
Thank you!

Comment: Does something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426245/95441 help?

Comment: Why do you want to plot it particularly? I don't really understand that part.

Comment: Because it is not possible to have it in cmyk color otherwise.

Comment: @Stefan I will have a look at it, as soon as I find the time.

Comment: @baghira, any news here?

Comment: @Stefan No sorry not yet. I have lots of other work.