# pgfplot zoom into coordiate set on plot and insert text

Tags: pgfplots, spy, zooming

I have managed to produce a nice looking graph, but want to add a "loop" that zooms into a specific threshold created by me (the 95th percentile). In the zoomed picture I'd like to be able to add text (to show what value x and y has), is this possible? Down below I have set up an illustration what I want it to look like, with the code being at the bottom (sorry for the amount of data points).

[image]

```
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{x}
    \label{DistributionFirmVisitors}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=3,connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,height=7cm,
    ylabel={Cumulative \% of EDGAR visitors},
    xlabel={\# of unique firms},
    xmin=-20, 
    xmax=1000,
    ymin=0.6, 
    ymax=1,
    xtick={1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000},
    ytick={0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1},
    tick label style={/pgf/number
    format/precision=5},
    scaled y ticks = false,
    legend pos=north east,
    grid style=dashed,
    every axis plot/.append style={thick},
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
    xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left
] 

\addplot[
    color=black,
    ]
  coordinates {

(1,0.690799792067144)
(2,0.815717915411241)
(3,0.863918774952765)
(4,0.890347737610418)
(5,0.907403411140743)
(6,0.919383533348833)
(7,0.928206053335568)
(8,0.935011547348293)
(9,0.940401744557027)
(10,0.944810451116085)
(11,0.948466588749695)
(12,0.951575349748817)
(13,0.954221564875537)
(14,0.956523229355536)
(15,0.958548102763598)
(16,0.960348636141617)
(17,0.961955603504048)
(18,0.963408320495485)
(19,0.964724812068291)
(20,0.965932013030725)
(21,0.967026084176588)
(22,0.968044228379768)
(23,0.968971638135861)
(24,0.969828396839549)
(25,0.970628967915434)
(26,0.971377432029224)
(27,0.972076415053081)
(28,0.972726641365533)
(29,0.973340642715111)
(30,0.973916584009543)
(31,0.97445662027495)
(32,0.974969039608988)
(33,0.97545103504486)
(34,0.975909608908335)
(35,0.976349958615349)
(36,0.976766240845779)
(37,0.977159964721558)
(38,0.977540064244528)
(39,0.977903158981559)
(40,0.978257156731579)
(41,0.978582994266332)
(42,0.978902795313355)
(43,0.979206195223212)
(44,0.979502906704663)
(45,0.97978390520855)
(46,0.980061136944092)
(47,0.980325643763498)
(48,0.980583136184159)
(49,0.980832231850386)
(50,0.981073824162364)
(51,0.9813087944473)
(52,0.981539623701653)
(53,0.981762146748888)
(54,0.981975723721305)
(55,0.982181640390791)
(56,0.982383917058175)
(57,0.982579589807982)
(58,0.982771417315103)
(59,0.982957648998098)
(60,0.983141212553516)
(61,0.983318099753503)
(62,0.983489783501065)
(63,0.983652696231955)
(64,0.983814818182951)
(65,0.983975268026846)
(66,0.984128944931506)
(67,0.984280140839709)
(68,0.984425034654721)
(69,0.984568992814134)
(70,0.984710439794652)
(71,0.984847166241763)
(72,0.984983729703706)
(73,0.985116176281015)
(74,0.985245218279245)
(75,0.985371489529606)
(76,0.985494120777865)
(77,0.985615846552964)
(78,0.985735338827603)
(79,0.98585315899514)
(80,0.985970484170684)
(81,0.986083740753496)
(82,0.986195089806186)
(83,0.986305310035669)
(84,0.986414817959601)
(85,0.986519828700173)
(86,0.986633356924933)
(87,0.986737347499078)
(88,0.986839931571582)
(89,0.986937614016048)
(90,0.987036733144594)
(91,0.987133594626729)
(92,0.987238949447101)
(93,0.987333806815309)
(94,0.98743030610818)
(95,0.987526038767109)
(96,0.987628429672005)
(97,0.987728713842683)
(98,0.987827398344113)
(99,0.987917028113945)
(100,0.988001116388041)
(101,0.988076481937365)
(102,0.988150344401243)
(103,0.988221695686226)
(104,0.988292232045365)
(105,0.988364941540087)
(106,0.988433956704318)
(107,0.988500702149161)
(108,0.988565672866612)
(109,0.988632013866778)
(110,0.988697262262664)
(111,0.988761037755544)
(112,0.988823992286093)
(113,0.988885208308175)
(114,0.988945687878753)
(115,0.989003233716295)
(116,0.989063182075953)
(117,0.989140129185063)
(118,0.989197017045441)
(119,0.98925286662993)
(120,0.989306573261275)
(121,0.989360877504904)
(122,0.989413678663089)
(123,0.989467216272777)
(124,0.989522902872097)
(125,0.989573150595972)
(126,0.989624774639049)
(127,0.989676151186129)
(128,0.989725119174604)
(129,0.989774793432144)
(130,0.98982272314473)
(131,0.989869439523281)
(132,0.989916035172078)
(133,0.989963180141259)
(134,0.990008320996513)
(135,0.990053703311276)
(136,0.990099224465257)
(137,0.990143405518961)
(138,0.99018842564446)
(139,0.990231580495251)

};

\addplot[mark=none, red, dashed, style=thin]
  coordinates {
(12, 0.951575349748817)
(12, 0)
};

\addplot[color=red, mark=none, dashed, style=thin] coordinates {(-20,0.951575349748817) (12,0.951575349748817)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \\
\end{center}
\end{figure} \vspace{0.4cm}
```

Comment: Please share  a compliable code with the list of packages used

Comment: What arguments do you pass to `\usetikzlibrary{}`?

Comment: Hi guys, I edited the code to include the packages and libraries. The package is pgfplots and the library is the tikzlibrary{spy}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer just shows some minor improvements to [marmot's already great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476033/95441). I define the coordinate to magnify *first* and then use this coordinate to add the red dashed lines, to place the "on spy" node and to write the coordinates of the to magnify point below the magnification. (I also decided to place the coordinate text *below* the magnification, because then nothing overlaps.)

For more details please have a look at the comments of the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Coordinate extraction
    % (see <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426245/95441>)
    % #1: node name
    % #2: output macro name: x coordinate
    % #3: output macro name: y coordinate
    \newcommand{\Getxycoords}[3]{%
        \pgfplotsextra{%
            % using `\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates' stores the (axis)
            % coordinates in `data point' which then can be called by
            % `\pgfkeysvalueof' or `\pgfkeysgetvalue'
            \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(#1)}%
            % `\global' (a TeX macro and not a TikZ/PGFPlots one) allows to
            % store the values globally
             \global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/x}{#2}%
             \global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/y}{#3}%
         }%
    }
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Because we need to give the spy node a name to add the labels afterwards,
    % it is a bit more complicate than usual. To do so we need to `scope` the
    % spy. To avoid further error messages it seems we need to `scope` the whole
    % `axis` environment.
    \begin{scope}[
        % Give the spy options to the `scope`
        spy using outlines={
            rectangle,
            magnification=3,
            connect spies,
            size=3cm,
            blue,
        },
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            width=12cm,
            height=7cm,
            ylabel={Cumulative \% of EDGAR visitors},
            xlabel={\# of unique firms},
            xmin=-20,
            xmax=1000,
            ymin=0.6,
            ymax=1,
            % (simplified this statement)
            xtick={1,100,200,...,1000},
            % (removed all unnecessary/unrelated stuff)
        ]

            % (simplified the plot by removing a lot of coordinates and adding
            %  `smooth` to the options
            \addplot [thick,smooth] coordinates {
                (1,0.690799792067144)
                (3,0.863918774952765)
                (5,0.907403411140743)
                (7,0.928206053335568)
                (8,0.935011547348293)
                (9,0.940401744557027)
                (10,0.944810451116085)
                (11,0.948466588749695)
                (12,0.951575349748817)
                (14,0.956523229355536)
                (16,0.960348636141617)
                (20,0.965932013030725)
                (25,0.970628967915434)
                (30,0.973916584009543)
                (35,0.976349958615349)
                (40,0.978257156731579)
                (50,0.981073824162364)
                (70,0.984710439794652)
                (100,0.988001116388041)
                (125,0.989573150595972)
                (139,0.990231580495251)
            };

            % crate a coordinate of the point you want to magnify
            \coordinate (point) at (axis cs:12,0.951575349748817);
            % Get the coordinates of that point (to later use them)
            \Getxycoords{point}{\PointX}{\PointY}

            % draw the dashed lines to the axis (using the defined coordinate)
            \draw [red,dashed]
                (point -| {axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0})
                    -| ({axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}} -| point);

            % unfortunately one cannot directly place the spy at an
            % axis coordinate, thus we define a `\coordinate` first
                \coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs:400,0.8);
            \spy on (point) in node (spy) at (spy point);

        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}

    % add the labels below the spy node
    \node [anchor=north] at (spy.south) {%
        $x = \pgfmathprintnumber{\PointX}$,
        $y = \pgfmathprintnumber{\PointY}$%
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

Please add an appropriate preamble to the codes of future questions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=3,
   width=3cm,height=4cm,connect spies}]
   \begin{axis}[width=12cm,height=7cm,
       ylabel={Cumulative \% of EDGAR visitors},
       xlabel={\# of unique firms},
       xmin=-20, 
       xmax=1000,
       ymin=0.6, 
       ymax=1,
       xtick={1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000},
       ytick={0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1},
       tick label style={/pgf/number
       format/precision=5},
       scaled y ticks = false,
       legend pos=north east,
       grid style=dashed,
       every axis plot/.append style={thick},
       axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
       xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left
   ] 

   \addplot[
       color=black,
       ]
     coordinates {

   (1,0.690799792067144)
   (2,0.815717915411241)
   (3,0.863918774952765)
   (4,0.890347737610418)
   (5,0.907403411140743)
   (6,0.919383533348833)
   (7,0.928206053335568)
   (8,0.935011547348293)
   (9,0.940401744557027)
   (10,0.944810451116085)
   (11,0.948466588749695)
   (12,0.951575349748817)
   (13,0.954221564875537)
   (14,0.956523229355536)
   (15,0.958548102763598)
   (16,0.960348636141617)
   (17,0.961955603504048)
   (18,0.963408320495485)
   (19,0.964724812068291)
   (20,0.965932013030725)
   (21,0.967026084176588)
   (22,0.968044228379768)
   (23,0.968971638135861)
   (24,0.969828396839549)
   (25,0.970628967915434)
   (26,0.971377432029224)
   (27,0.972076415053081)
   (28,0.972726641365533)
   (29,0.973340642715111)
   (30,0.973916584009543)
   (31,0.97445662027495)
   (32,0.974969039608988)
   (33,0.97545103504486)
   (34,0.975909608908335)
   (35,0.976349958615349)
   (36,0.976766240845779)
   (37,0.977159964721558)
   (38,0.977540064244528)
   (39,0.977903158981559)
   (40,0.978257156731579)
   (41,0.978582994266332)
   (42,0.978902795313355)
   (43,0.979206195223212)
   (44,0.979502906704663)
   (45,0.97978390520855)
   (46,0.980061136944092)
   (47,0.980325643763498)
   (48,0.980583136184159)
   (49,0.980832231850386)
   (50,0.981073824162364)
   (51,0.9813087944473)
   (52,0.981539623701653)
   (53,0.981762146748888)
   (54,0.981975723721305)
   (55,0.982181640390791)
   (56,0.982383917058175)
   (57,0.982579589807982)
   (58,0.982771417315103)
   (59,0.982957648998098)
   (60,0.983141212553516)
   (61,0.983318099753503)
   (62,0.983489783501065)
   (63,0.983652696231955)
   (64,0.983814818182951)
   (65,0.983975268026846)
   (66,0.984128944931506)
   (67,0.984280140839709)
   (68,0.984425034654721)
   (69,0.984568992814134)
   (70,0.984710439794652)
   (71,0.984847166241763)
   (72,0.984983729703706)
   (73,0.985116176281015)
   (74,0.985245218279245)
   (75,0.985371489529606)
   (76,0.985494120777865)
   (77,0.985615846552964)
   (78,0.985735338827603)
   (79,0.98585315899514)
   (80,0.985970484170684)
   (81,0.986083740753496)
   (82,0.986195089806186)
   (83,0.986305310035669)
   (84,0.986414817959601)
   (85,0.986519828700173)
   (86,0.986633356924933)
   (87,0.986737347499078)
   (88,0.986839931571582)
   (89,0.986937614016048)
   (90,0.987036733144594)
   (91,0.987133594626729)
   (92,0.987238949447101)
   (93,0.987333806815309)
   (94,0.98743030610818)
   (95,0.987526038767109)
   (96,0.987628429672005)
   (97,0.987728713842683)
   (98,0.987827398344113)
   (99,0.987917028113945)
   (100,0.988001116388041)
   (101,0.988076481937365)
   (102,0.988150344401243)
   (103,0.988221695686226)
   (104,0.988292232045365)
   (105,0.988364941540087)
   (106,0.988433956704318)
   (107,0.988500702149161)
   (108,0.988565672866612)
   (109,0.988632013866778)
   (110,0.988697262262664)
   (111,0.988761037755544)
   (112,0.988823992286093)
   (113,0.988885208308175)
   (114,0.988945687878753)
   (115,0.989003233716295)
   (116,0.989063182075953)
   (117,0.989140129185063)
   (118,0.989197017045441)
   (119,0.98925286662993)
   (120,0.989306573261275)
   (121,0.989360877504904)
   (122,0.989413678663089)
   (123,0.989467216272777)
   (124,0.989522902872097)
   (125,0.989573150595972)
   (126,0.989624774639049)
   (127,0.989676151186129)
   (128,0.989725119174604)
   (129,0.989774793432144)
   (130,0.98982272314473)
   (131,0.989869439523281)
   (132,0.989916035172078)
   (133,0.989963180141259)
   (134,0.990008320996513)
   (135,0.990053703311276)
   (136,0.990099224465257)
   (137,0.990143405518961)
   (138,0.99018842564446)
   (139,0.990231580495251)

   };

   \addplot[mark=none, red, dashed, style=thin]
     coordinates {(-20,0.951575349748817)
   (12, 0.951575349748817)
   (12, 0)
   };
   \path (12, 0.951575349748817) coordinate (X);
  \end{axis}
  \spy [red] on (X) in node (zoom) [left] at ([xshift=8cm,yshift=-2cm]X);
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=south,fill=gray!5] at (zoom.south) {$x=12,y=0.95$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Marmot, that is exactly what I was looking for! I'm going to look for ways to implement a circle style, but that I can figure out myself. However, I am pretty new to LaTeX and I am having problems with identifying which parts I put into the preamble, besides the usepackages? I was under the impression that documentclass is strictly used ONCE in the preamble (it is for my thesis..).

Comment: @Philip, you are right, you only need the first "document" of marmot's code. I guess he (also) has a "playing" TeX file and just copied a bit too much ;) I am pretty sure he will correct that shortly.

Comment: @Philip Yes, it is precisely as Stefan was saying: I copied too much. Sorry about that!

Comment: No need to be sorry, you really helped! Thank you.