# Sphere shading in cmyk colours

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, printing, shading

I'm trying to make a sphere in cmyk colours. In rgb, the spheres are nicely overlapping as expected. Is the solution using @Christian Feuersänger suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137031/49888)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}
\definecolor{greyR}{RGB}{102,102,102}
\definecolor{darkR}{RGB}{75,75,75}
\definecolor{darkC}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.80}
\definecolor{greyC}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.70}
% Define shading (RGB)
\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphereR}{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{0.35cm}}{%
color(0cm)=(white);
color(0.7cm)=(greyR);
color(0.85cm)=(darkR)
}
% Define shading (CMYK)
\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphereC}{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{0.35cm}}{%
color(0cm)=(white);
color(0.7cm)=(greyC);
color(0.85cm)=(darkC)
}
\newcommand*{\myBallR}[3]{\fill [shading=sphereR,darkR] (#1,#2) circle (1cm) node[black] {rgb};}
\newcommand*{\myBallC}[3]{\fill [shading=sphereC,darkC] (#1,#2) circle (1cm) node[black] {cmyk};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=darkR] node[black,above=-3pt] {\footnotesize rgb} (-2cm, 0cm) rectangle (2cm,2cm)  ;
\draw [fill=darkC] node[black,below=-3pt] {\footnotesize cmyk} (-2cm,-2cm) rectangle (2cm,0cm);
\myBallR{.98}{.98};
\myBallR{.98}{-.98};
\myBallC{-.98}{.98};
\myBallC{-.98}{-.98};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update

Since version 3.1.3, `pgf` now supports CMYK (and grayscale) shadings. Instead of `\usepackage{pgf-cmykshadings}`, just use `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}` before loading `tikz`.

---

As you are aware, `pgf` only supports shadings in RGB. But it is now possible to output shadings in CMYK and grayscale using a new package, `pgf-cmykshadings`.

`pgf-cmykshadings` should be loaded *before* `tikz` to ensure the `tikz` shadings are set up to allow for output in the CMYK colour space.

## MWE

This MWE follows the question and shows both RGB and CMYK spheres. In a real world document you would probably want to force all colours everywhere to be CMYK by loading `xcolor` with the `cmyk` option and not changing the colour model.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{greyR}{RGB}{102,102,102}
\definecolor{darkR}{RGB}{75,75,75}
\definecolor{darkC}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.80}
\definecolor{greyC}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.70}
% Define shading (RGB)
\selectcolormodel{rgb} % select the RGB colour model to define an RGB shading
\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphereR}{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{0.35cm}}{%
color(0cm)=(white);
color(0.7cm)=(greyR);
color(0.85cm)=(darkR)
}
% Define shading (CMYK)
\selectcolormodel{cmyk} % select the CMYK colour model to define a CMYK shading
\pgfdeclareradialshading{sphereC}{\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{0.35cm}}{%
color(0cm)=(white);
color(0.7cm)=(greyC);
color(0.85cm)=(darkC)
}
\selectcolormodel{natural} % return to the natural colour model so we can use both RGB and CMYK colours
\newcommand*{\myBallR}[3]{\fill [shading=sphereR,darkR] (#1,#2) circle (1cm) node[black] {rgb};}
\newcommand*{\myBallC}[3]{\fill [shading=sphereC,darkC] (#1,#2) circle (1cm) node[black] {cmyk};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=darkR] node[black,above=-3pt] {\footnotesize rgb} (-2cm, 0cm) rectangle (2cm,2cm)  ;
\draw [fill=darkC] node[black,below=-3pt] {\footnotesize cmyk} (-2cm,-2cm) rectangle (2cm,0cm);
\myBallR{.98}{.98};
\myBallR{.98}{-.98};
\myBallC{-.98}{.98};
\myBallC{-.98}{-.98};
\node at (0,2.2cm) {\textcolor{cyan}{C} \textcolor{magenta}{M}
\textcolor{yellow}{Y} K};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Composite output

Note the mismatched shades of grey.

[image]

### Separations

Note that the CMYK sphere and bottom CMYK background appears only on the black plate, but the RGB spheres and top RGB background separate out onto all four plates.

The separations below were made using the GhostScript `tiffsep` device.

#### Cyan Plate

[image]

#### Magenta Plate

[image]

#### Yellow Plate

[image]

#### Black Plate

[image]