# Using pgfplots for shading in tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tcolorbox

**Background**: I am using `tcolorbox` to build my theorem, definition, and example environments. I've been using a shading for the background of these environments, but recently learned that the shading in `pgf` is hard-coded to RGB, but I have to use CMYK for printing purposes.

`pgfplots` is capable of doing shading in CMYK colorspace, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136818/how-do-i-force-tikz-to-use-cmyk-everywhere-also-in-shadings).

**Problem:** `tcolorbox` appears to use `pgf` to do its shading. Is it possible to instead have `tcolorbox` use `pgfplots` to do its shading, preferably in an automatic way?

For example, here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\tcbset{
definitionstyle/.style={%
enhanced,
interior style={left color=black!2, right color=blue!30}
}
}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[definitionstyle]
Blah blah
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to replace the `left color=black!2, right color!30` with something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x=1cm,y=1cm,hide axis]
\addplot[surf,mesh/color input=explicit,shader=interp] 
table[meta=cdata]{
x y cdata
1 1 color=black!2
2 1 color=blue!30

1 2 color=black!2
2 2 color=blue!30
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which would do the shading in `pgfplots` with CMYK colors.

Answer (score 5):

The TikZ `\shade` command can be used in an underlay, for example. I don't think `pgfplots` is necessary here.

Don't forget to use `\begin{tcbclipinterior}...\end{tcbclipinterior}` to get the correct clipping of the shading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
definitionstyle/.style={%
  enhanced,
  underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
      \shade[left color=black!2, right color=blue!30] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
    \end{tcbclipinterior} 
  },
}
}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[definitionstyle]
Blah blah
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had misunderstood what worked in pgfplots to output in CMYK and have updated the question to accurately reflect what actually works. I like your idea behind using an `underlay` with `tcbclipinterior`, but the shading as written outputs in RGB. I tried to replace that with the `pgfplots` shading (see the updated question) but it doesn't compile (complains of runaway argument, extra `}`, pgf math error, illegal unit of measure, etc).

Answer (score 1):

(Warning: Very Hacky solution)

Using Christian's idea of `tcbclipinterior` and `underlay`, I came up with the following way of making sure that everything is CMYK.

Firstly, the following code is used to produce a page which is entirely shading:

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{tikz}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.5in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0, ymin=0, x=9in,y=13in, hide axis]
    \addplot[surf,mesh/color input=explicit,shader=interp] 
    table[meta=cdata] {
        x y cdata
        0 0 color=black!4
        1 0 color=teal!20

        0 1 color=black!4
        1 1 color=teal!20
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output has an extra blank page at the front, so remove that (I printed the second page as a PDF only, then I selected Preflight and perform "Analyze and Fix" (this step is done because otherwise there will be "device independent colors" which arise later). Let's say the final result is the file `background.pdf`.  Then we can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
definitionstyle/.style={%
  enhanced,
  underlay={
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \includegraphics{background.pdf}
    \end{tcbclipinterior} 
  }
}
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[definitionstyle]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

This will produce a pdf with no RGB.

An additional comment I will make is that if you're using any nodes (as I was), you can add 
`\tcbuselibrary{skins}`
and then add 
`fill plain image=background.pdf` 
to the options for the node.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked quite a time ago, but I think I have a new answer for it.

I follow the original idea of replacing the conventional shading by a `pgfplots` shading. The `axis` environment of `pgfplots` is used inside `fill overzoom picture` to be scaled into the given node, here, the background of a `tcolorbox`.

Unfortunately, the code cannot applied directly into the new style `definitionstyle cmyk` for some technical reasons (at least I could'nt do it). I guess (but do not know) that the code is scanned as verbatim by `pgfplots`. My clumsy but working solution is to save the code in a file and input that file at the required place.

The complete example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{tcbverbatimwrite}{\jobname_myshading.tex}
\begin{axis}[x=1cm,y=1cm,hide axis]
\addplot[surf,mesh/color input=explicit,shader=interp]
table[meta=cdata]{
x y cdata
1 1 color=black!2
2 1 color=blue!30

1 2 color=black!2
2 2 color=blue!30
};
\end{axis}
\end{tcbverbatimwrite}

\tcbset{
  definitionstyle/.style={%
    enhanced,
    interior style={left color=black!2, right color=blue!30}
  },
  definitionstyle cmyk/.style={%
    enhanced,
    interior style={fill overzoom picture={\input{\jobname_myshading.tex}}}
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[definitionstyle]
Shading RGB
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[definitionstyle cmyk]
Shading CMYK via pgfplots
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]