# LaTeX: Inconsistent colors in PDF

Tags: color, pdf, tcolorbox, cmyk

I am using `tcolorbox`es with grey frames for examples in my PhD thesis. It will be printed professionally and the sample print I received shows inconsistent colors. The `tcolorbox`es are created identically with a grey frame `\definecolor{framegrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.15}`.

However when inspecting the PDF with *Acrobat Professional* I see that on some pages the grey frame is defined with the correct cmyk color `(0,0,0,0.15)`, on other pages it is set with a different cmyk color `(0.09,0.07,0.07,0)`! These pages tend to have colorful pixel graphics inside the `tcolorbox`.

The framecolors looks identical on the screen, the resulting colors in print are different!

**Does anybody know how to get consistent colors from LaTeX?**

- `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}` does not solve the problem
- `colframe=white!85!black` results in similar problems

I cannot give a minimal working example at the moment, as I don't know what exactly is producing this behaviour.

The two colors look very similar.

[image: wrong color in tcolorbox]

**Additional information**

I found out, that compiling the document on Fedora 30 results in the above problem, while compiling it on Debian Stretch yields correctly defined framegrey in CMYK.

I did check the `tikz` version as suggested in the comments, but both systems have version 3.0.1a installed (< version 3.1.3).

Here you find a list of all differences in the tex environment on both systems:

```
--- Fedora 30
+++ Debian Stretch
[...]
   xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
    color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
-  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
+  pdftex.def    2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX
+infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
+ ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
[...]
-graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
+graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
-graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
+graphics.sty    2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
[...]
-fancyhdr.sty    2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
-multicol.sty    2018/04/20 v1.8s multicolumn formatting (FMi)
+fancyhdr.sty    2016/09/06 3.8 Extensive control of page headers and footers
+multicol.sty    2016/04/07 v1.8p multicolumn formatting (FMi)
[...]
-inputenc.sty    2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
-microtype.sty    2018/01/14 v2.7a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
-microtype-pdftex.def    2018/01/14 v2.7a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
-microtype.cfg    2018/01/14 v2.7a microtype main configuration file (RS)
-mathtools.sty    2018/01/08 v1.21 mathematical typesetting tools
-    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
- mhsetup.sty    2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
+inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
+    utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
+   t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
+  ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
+  omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
+microtype.sty    2016/05/14 v2.6a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
+microtype-pdftex.def    2016/05/14 v2.6a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
+microtype.cfg    2016/05/14 v2.6a microtype main configuration file (RS)
+mathtools.sty    2015/11/12 v1.18 mathematical typesetting tools
+    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
+ mhsetup.sty    2010/01/21 v1.2a programming setup (MH)
[...]
-pgfplots.sty    2018/03/28 v1.16 Data Visualization (1.16)
+pgfplots.sty    2016/08/10 v1.14 Data Visualization (1.14)
     tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
      pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
   pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
[...]
-pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
-infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
- ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
-   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
+pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
+   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
[...]
-pgfplotstable.sty    2018/03/28 v1.16 Table typesetting and Pretty-printing (1.
-16)
-   array.sty    2018/04/30 v2.4h Tabular extension package (FMi)
+pgfplotstable.sty    2016/08/10 v1.14 Table typesetting and Pretty-printing (1.
+14)
+   array.sty    2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
[...]
- caption.sty    2018/05/01 v3.3-147 Customizing captions (AR)
-caption3.sty    2018/05/27 v1.8a caption3 kernel (AR)
+ caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
+caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
[...]
-algorithm2e.sty    2017/07/18 v5.2 algorithms environments
-ifoddpage.sty    2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
+algorithm2e.sty    2013/01/06 v5.00 algorithms environments
[...]
-tcolorbox.sty    2018/07/26 version 4.14 text color boxes
+tcolorbox.sty    2016/11/18 version 3.96 text color boxes
[...]
-etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
-  xparse.sty    2018-05-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
-   expl3.sty    2018-06-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
-expl3-code.tex    2018-06-14 L3 programming layer 
-l3pdfmode.def    2018-06-14 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
+etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
+  xparse.sty    2016/11/21 v6760 L3 Experimental document command parser
+   expl3.sty    2016/11/21 v6760 L3 programming layer (loader) 
+expl3-code.tex    2016/11/21 v6760 L3 programming layer 
+l3pdfmode.def    2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
[...]
- siunitx.sty    2018/05/17 v2.7s A comprehensive (SI) units package
-l3keys2e.sty    2018-05-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
-translator.sty    2018/01/04 v1.12 Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
-hyperref.sty    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
+ siunitx.sty    2017/01/01 v2.7a A comprehensive (SI) units package
+l3keys2e.sty    2016/11/21 v6760 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
+translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
+translator-language-mappings.tex
+hyperref.sty    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
[...]
-  pd1enc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
+  pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
[...]
- hpdftex.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
+ hpdftex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
[...]
-  ts1enc.dfu    2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
+  ts1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
[...]
-siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
+siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2017/01/01 v2.7a siunitx: Abbreviated units
```

Comment: Can you share some code, that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: I am not at all an expert on color theory but colors seem to be completely specified by three coordinates, `R`, `G` and `B` for example. So if a color model uses four coordinates, then there must be degeneracies.

Comment: what happen if you use `\definecolor{framegrey}{HTML}{D9D9D9}`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat cmyk uses four values (for c=cyan, m=magenta,y=yellow,k=black).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand that. My statement is that if three components are sufficient to fix a position of something, and someone comes with fourdimensional description, there will be degeneracies. It does not mean that the 4d description is crap.

Comment: This looks like the problem described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137031/9632).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer from this [site](https://htmlcolors.com/cmyk-to-hex) seem that there is degeneracy. cmyk=(0.02,0,0,0.07) is the same as cmyk=(0.09,0.07,0.07,0)

Comment: @Sveinung is probably right, but we need a MWE to be sure. But the good news is that `tikz` now supports CMYK shadings if you are using at least version 3.1.3. If you are stuck with earlier versions, then `pgf-cmykshadings` will help you. See the other answer in the linked question.

Comment: Make sure that you are setting the colour model to CMYK *before* you load `tikz`. You could put `\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}` before your `\documentclass` line to make sure of this. Although, if your document class doesn't load `xcolor` then it is enough to load it early on.

Comment: And check that your version of `tikz` is new enough.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat RGB is an additive colour model, while CMYK is a subtractive model. They have different optimal uses, where RGB is better for digital and CMYK is better for print. Google it, it's quite interesting material :-)

Comment: @Holene My statement does not contradict this. It is only that there are degeneracies. It is a very simple statement.. All I am saying is that if you have a mapping from R^3 -> R^4, there will be degeneracies. Just Google linear algebra, you will love it. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat That's the other way around. Continuous embeddings R³ → R⁴ certainly exist (in particular linear); there is no continuous embedding in the other direction. The problem is that no homeomorphism exists from R³ to R⁴.

Comment: @egreg Yes, thanks. But what I want to say is that the coordinates in CMYK cannot be unique. Why on earth one wants to use 3 coordinates, I do not understand either, isn't that just a simple wave length?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat In theory, yes. But screens and printers are not able to produce every wave length. Screens use three different base color and approximate the wave length; printers use four parameters. The purpose of color profiles is to provide an “exact” (actually well approximated) conversion from RGB to CMYK, which depends on the printer; `xcolor` tries to do the conversion, but it cannot be “exact”, so it's better to stick to a single color model.

Comment: @egreg I agree with that statement. Nonetheless there *must* be two different CMYK values that yield the same color. This is all I wanted to say.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat That's a mapping R⁴ → R³, so, yes. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg This is all I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be divided in sub-questions:

1. How do I create a document for professional printing?
2. How do I eliminate the differences between compiling a document in Fedora30 and Debian Stretch?

As a preferred Windows user I can only directly answer #1: You should create a document that directly complies to one of the PDF/X standards. As long as you want one document for the archives/libraries and for print, this standard should be PDF/X-4 and the base colour model should be CMYK. (PFD/X-1 is paper-only, PDF/X-3 is the outdated version of PDF/X-4.) A minimal example of PDF/X you can find in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227429/pdf-a-with-cmyk-how/536060#536060).

Minimal working examples (MWE) take a while to create but they are incredibly useful. Does the problem persist when you compile the MWE fom above augmented by colour? In MikTeX with normal coloured text I do not see this behaviour.

I see your packages are outdated. Update your distribution to the latest version.

You do not specify *how* in Acrobat you read the colour values. There is no colour picker in Acrobat. The correct way to check is with the `Output Preview` of the `Print Production` tool. Select the `OutputIntent` as your simulation profile and choose only `Process Color`. Is your text visible? If yes, it's OK. An alternative way is to set `\pdfobjcompresslevel=0, \pdfcompresslevel=0` and edit the file in a text editor. You should find the values 0 0 0 .15 if the colours were correctly written to PDF.