Why don't the colors match in this tikzpicture?
Consider the following picture:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{tu-red}{cmyk/HTML}{0.20,1.00,1.00,0/c40d1e}
\definecolor{tu-violet}{cmyk/HTML}{.75,.80,0,0/9013fe}
%\selectcolormodel{rgb}
%\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{red-violet}{100bp}{color(25bp)=(tu-red); color(75bp)=(tu-violet)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \fill[tu-violet] (current page.center) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[tu-red] (current page.center) rectangle (current page.north west);
        \shade[left color=tu-red, right color=tu-violet] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}

The colors of the endpoints of the shading and the rectangles don't match. However, if one of the two \selectcolormodel lines is uncommented, they do. What is the default color model then, if neither cmyk nor rgb, and why don't the colors of the shading and the rectangles agree, despite them being the same color name?

Some background information: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456402/36296

Your two colors, tu-red and tu-violet are defined in a certain model.  I guess you should continue by setting it as the model for your drawing.  Anyway, if you define the colors in the rgb model (let's say usual), you'll have no problem, that is you don't have to declare a model afterwards.

@DanielN Maybe I misunderstand what \definecolor{...}{multiple/models} does. I thought it does declare the same color w.r.t. different models, of which then the declaration matching the document's model is used. This seems to be wrong. What does \definecolor do if multiple models are passed?

It is not clear for me; in the manual, mulitple models, i.e. model-list  comes with spec-list, with, I would say a bijection between the two lists (as you use it).  But there are phrases there about a core-model and something like as set by a package option or the \selectcolormodel command.  I think, by default, there is no model chosen by tikz, but I'm not sure.  You can always load xcolor with an argument specifying the color model before loading tikz.
